# Adjugate matrix entries: generalized formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want a formula for the $i,j$ entry of the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) $\text{adj}(A)$.
I found this:

> $$[\text{adj}(A)]_{ij}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\epsilon_{i_{1}\ldots i_{n-1}i} \epsilon_{j_{1}\ldots j_{n-1}j}a_{i_1 j_1}a_{i_2 j_2}\ldots a_{i_{n-1} j_{n-1}}$$

but I don't get it.

> *What's $\epsilon$? What means $a_{i_x j_y}$?*

Source in spanish: [Matriz de adjuntos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_de_adjuntos). The formula is in this spanish reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the reference you used, the $a$'s are the elements of the matrix and the epsilons are the Levi-Civita tensor using Einstein summation convention. For a $3 \times 3$ matrix, it is

> $$\text{adj}(A)_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{mni}\epsilon_{pqj}a_{mp}a_{nq}\tag{1}$$

Look in you reference the total $3 \times 3$ matrix

[image]

See for instance the first element of this $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ matrix

Lets see if the equation $(1)$ works

$$\operatorname{adj}(A)_{11} = (1/2)\sum_{m,n,p,q}\epsilon_{mn1}\epsilon_{pq1}a_{mp}a_{nq} =$$ $$=(1/2)( \epsilon_{231}(\epsilon_{231}a_{22}a_{33}+\epsilon_{321}a_{23}a_{32}) + \epsilon_{321}(\epsilon_{231}a_{32}a_{23}+\epsilon_{321}a_{33}a_{22})) = $$

$$=(1/2)(a_{22}a_{33}-a_{23}a_{32} + a_{32}a_{23}-a_{33}a_{22} = a_{22}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{32} \implies $$

> $$\operatorname{adj}(A)_{11} = a_{22}a_{33} - a_{23}a_{32}$$

Which is correct looking the matrix above.